# Remove info message after two sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having this code which is provide the user info message on top of the page,
Currently its there until user click on X button,my question is if there is a way
to remove like fade out this message automatically after 2 sec if user does not click on X ?

```
   function addessage(message) {
        $messages.html("<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this using [**`.delay()`**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$messages.html("your html as is").delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thanks ,can I change the fade out to be more slow?

Comment: yes you can provide time in ms like `.fadeOut(1000)` for one second or you can do this also like `.fadeOut('slow')`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function addessage(message) {
    $messages.html("<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");

    setTimeout(function(){$('.alert.alert-info').fadeOut();}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout

```
function addessage(message) {
    $messages.html("<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Information : </strong>" + message + "<button type='button' class='close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $messages.empty();
    }, 2000);
}
```